# Java Swing - MultiThread and Repaint

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, repaint

I'm drawing charts in 4 JPanels by selecting in a JComboBox the Item from which I should read informations to draw.
The selection starts a Thread who readInformations() and repaint() every second.
It works fine about information reading, but when i select back an Item already started, it doesn't repaint the entire chart, but begin from the current information, so it lost a part of chart.

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame
{
       private ArrayList<Item> items;
       public MainClass()
       {
            items = new ArrayList();
       }

       private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
       { 
            if(!items.get((jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex())).isRunning())
            {
                items.get(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()).start();
            }

            for(int i=0; i<forni.size(); i++)
            {
               if(forni.get(i).isRunning() && 
               forni.get(i) != forni.get(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()))
               {
                  jPanel1.remove(items.get(i).getChart1());
                  jPanel2.remove(items.get(i).getChart2());
                  jPanel3.remove(items.get(i).getChart3());
                  jPanel4.remove(items.get(i).getChart4());
               }
            }

             jPanel1.add(forni.get(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()).getChart1());
             jPanel2.add(forni.get(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()).getChart2());
             jPanel3.add(forni.get(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()).getChart3());
             jPanel4.add(forni.get(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()).getChart4());

             jPanel1.revalidate();
             jPanel2.revalidate();
             jPanel3.revalidate();
             jPanel4.revalidate();

        }  
 }
```

Item Class

```
 import java.util.Timer;
 public class Item
 {
     private Chart chart1;
     private Chart chart2;
     private Chart chart3;
     private Chart chart4;

     private Timer timer;

     private boolean running = false;

     public Item()
     {
         timer = new Timer();
         chart1 = new Chart();
         //...
     }

     public void start()
     {
        running = true;
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
        {
           @Override
           public void run() 
           {
                read();
                repaint();
           }
         }, 1000,1000);
     }

      private void read()
      {
         chart1.read();
         //....
      }
      private void repaint()
      {
         chart1.repaint();
         //...
      }

      public Boolean isRunning()
      {
          return running; 
      }


// And the getting methods that return a JComponent

}
```

The Chart class extends JComponent and his paintComponent() method just redraw the entire array of points updated.

Comment: You're essentially asking "why is my code not working" and not showing **any code** which likely isn't going to allow us to be able to provide an answer. Please fix this by creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I provide immediately

Comment: Thank you for providing code, but if the answers below don't help you solve your problem, please have another critical look at the link I've provided as it explains exactly what type of code we'll want you to post.

Answer (score 2):

To refresh UI from thread use SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait() from javadoc

```
 Causes <code>doRun.run()</code> to be executed synchronously on the
 AWT event dispatching thread.  This call blocks until
 all pending AWT events have been processed and (then)
 <code>doRun.run()</code> returns. This method should
 be used when an application thread needs to update the GUI
```

or SwingUtilities.invokeLater() from javadoc

```
Causes <i>doRun.run()</i> to be executed asynchronously on the
AWT event dispatching thread.  This will happen after all
pending AWT events have been processed.  This method should
be used when an application thread needs to update the GUI.
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you wrote you use `java.util.Timer`. Take a look at [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) whose `ActionListener`s are invoked in the EDT where it is safe to make GUI changes and do painting works.

But keep in mind that you should not do lengthy works in the EDT because that will make the GUI unresponsive. If that is the case, check out the [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to balance between lengthy jobs and short codes to update the UI.

If you want to stick to your separate thread, `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` and `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` are your friends.

If you want to look more into it, read the official Oracle tutorial: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Without seeing the read method, a SwingWorker might be a better choice